# Howto recover corrupted videos from a SD card?

Tags: video, data-recovery, sd-card, file-corruption

I had some videos that I deleted with a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I added the video files on my computer, took my SD card out of computer and I wanted to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on an APP, but it did it on my desktop. Then the computer tried to put the files back on the SD card, but it wasn't present. So he deleted the files.

I recovered them with `Recuva`, but now there are corrupted.. I can read the videos, but the screen is black and we can only hear: Scrrrhhh.. Wrhhee.. Brchhhhe. (Yes, it is hard to write sounds) Except for some short moments where we can here the normal sound of the video.

Somebody told me that the video files are alive, but the one who have to read them is corrupted. (Like if you try to read English with French, you don't understand anything)

So.. Can somebody help me?
I tried some free apps, but they didn't succeed to recover them.
But they succeeded in recovering one picture of the video.

Here is a link to download one of the corrupted videos if you want to see them: http://www.mediafire.com/file/p9qzv4m6hfd5f94/%255B000242%255D.mov/file

Comment: Have you tried using an undelete utility? (Before ypu attempt this, do a bit copy backup of the USB disk).  Its unlikely that a block based rexovery system will work because the files are likely fragmented. Depending on how the files were deleted its possible the info is still in the File Allocation Table and the file.can be recovered

Comment: The corrupted videos themselves do not have the data, so looking to fix them wont help.  Also, how big.is the SD card?

Comment: the SD card is 16GB

Answer (score 1):

Most of the undelete tools fail when recovering deleted video files due to file fragmentation. They just can't allocate video file chunks scattered across the SD card.

To recover a deleted video file, you would have to analyze the SD card cluster-by-cluster to collect all those video file chunks and then combine them into a final file. If the video files are important to you, I'd suggest to stick with the following guide:

1. Make sure to lock the SD card with the switch on the side of the card. Do not put your card into a reader before you locked it with the switch. MacOS and most of the camera models write their temp files on the SD card as long as you put the card into the slot. So, even if you haven't specifically written any new files to the SD card, your deleted video files may still be overwritten with the temp files, if you haven't locked the card. If you have a microSD card, then put it into an SD adapter and then lock it the same way.
2. Create a RAW image of the SD card. This must be an IMG file that contains the exact copy of all clusters of your SD card. If you have a 64 GB SD card, then the image file size will be exactly 64 GB. If you're a Mac user, you will have to use the Terminal to create such an image file. On Windows you can use some free tools, like USB Image Tool. Let me know if you have troubles with this - I'll create a guide for you.
3. Once you have the image file, you can use it as a backup and the source for recovering your video file. You can try different video recovery tools, but the chances are quite low. As I've already mentioned, the best option would be to analyze your image file manually. There are recovery services out there. You can upload your image to a cloud storage provider and then share the link with them.

Hope this is helpful.